# best way to make thousands of API calls simultaneously

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a expressJS backend.

Let's say I want to make 10 000 calls to an API one after an other and store the data I get back in a DB.

What is the best way to do that? I guess `Promise.all` is out of the picture because if one requests fails, all fail, right?

Some kind of loop doesn't seem right because of the async nature of the call.

I want to know when all calls are finished though because I want to flag that in my DB.

How can I do this in JavaScript(nodejs, express)?

EDIT: Okay, I want to make the calls one after another. What's the best way to ensure all calls return data? A queue system maybe?

Comment: you've described two different ways of doing this that aren't similar. *"API at once, or one after another"* you either want to send them in parallel, or one after the other... they're quite different in purpose, result, and logic. one isn't "better" than the other

Comment: 10,000 is definitely more than you want to try to run in parallel. If you don't do them in series then you should, at least, batch them.

Comment: This also seems like something best kept away from Express and in its own service.

Comment: So you're grabbing monstrous amounts of data from an API and storing it in your own database? That sounds like stealing, and highly unethical.

Comment: @Andy It's NFT metadata from IPFS

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what's the actual context here. But if we ignore that & all the questions regarding whether 10000 parallel requests to API is wise or not, you could probably evaluate `Promise.allSettled` if your env supports it.

Comment: gonna try this. thanks

Comment: How did it work out, @16bbstack?